# Extracting packet informations using C++

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, networking, wireshark

I have been messing with Wireshark for a while, and I wonder if anyone could help me. I have recorded a random browsing with it, and I saved it to a pcap file. I would like to create a C/**C++** program (I know many exist, but I want to practise) that extracts every info from the packets, like source and target IP, port used, data, etc. My finish goal in learning is to extract an image or a Youtube video or anything from the stream (I know, I'll have to group the packets and sort them, etc.), but that's a later project I guess. :)

I am using libpcap (on Linux), and my code so far can read the offline file packet by packet, and - since I know they are PPP packets in my case - if I load a self defined structure with the info from the 20th byte of the packet, I can view the mac addresses and the ip addresses.

My problems:

1) How do I know/determine without Wireshark that what kind of data link type, is used? (Ethernet, WiFi, PPP, etc)

2) How do I read further data of packets? If I just read one byte, my program doesn't do *anything*, every variable gets empty.

I have a ppphdr struct, which contains:

```
u_int16_t htype;
u_int16_t ptype;
u_char hplen;
u_char plen;
u_int16_t oper;
u_char sha[6];
u_char spa[4];
u_char tha[6];
u_char tpa[4];
```

And I call this for every packet:

```
pppheader = (struct ppphdr*)(packet+20);
```

Because the ppp frame starts from the 20th byte. It gives back sender and target mac and IP address.

After I continue reading the next few bytes, with the same call just different struct, it comes back empty, and the program stops after 1 packet. I'm trying to use this guide: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_PPPGeneralFrameFormat.htm

Comment: start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame

Comment: You will have much higher chance of getting a reasonable answer, if you add a bit of code to the question, and also some information about what capture files you have, exactly. Especially problem 2 sounds like a problem with your code.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap

Comment: (continuing from above..), once you have the frame, then you can extract the ip headers, and then from there either tcp/udp headers, and each level will expose some specific bits of information..

Comment: I think I would recommend looking at the source code for `tshark`, `tcpdump` and other such tools. Basically, you need to know the structure of each layer of protocol headers/trailers for every type of packet you're interested in, which is, well... quite a lot of information...

Comment: No1 and No3: I know the frames, my problem is that after reading the frame, I just get some empty characters.

Comment: Added some source code.

Comment: The "ppphdr" structure you show is actually an [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) packet, so it won't work to dissect PPP headers.  You want something like what's shown in the "tcpipguide.com" document you cited, although note that you might not have the "flag" field in your packets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I know/determine without Wireshark that what kind of data link type, is used? (Ethernet, WiFi, PPP, etc)

Wireshark itself works with different file formats. Two of them that you are probably interested in are "pcap" and "pcap-ng".

If you have recorded data in "pcap" format, the link type is stored in the "Link-layer header type" field in the pcap file header; see [the pcap-savefile man page](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-savefile.5.html).

If you have recorded data using "pcap-ng" format, then link type is stored in [Interface Description Block](http://www.winpcap.org/ntar/draft/PCAP-DumpFileFormat.html#sectionidb).

You can read more about these two formats [here](http://www.winpcap.org/ntar/draft/PCAP-DumpFileFormat.html) and [there](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat).

If you are reading a pcap or pcap-ng file with libpcap, the `pcap_datalink()` routine will return a `DLT_` value specifying the link-layer header type.  See [the list of link-layer header types](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) for a description of the `DLT_` values and the headers that correspond to them.  `DLT_EN10MB` is for Ethernet (the "10MB" is historical - it's used for all Ethernet speeds); `DLT_PPP` is the most likely type for PPP.  If you have Wi-Fi packets with Wi-Fi headers (if you don't capture in monitor mode, you'll probably get Ethernet headers, and `DLT_EN10MB` on Wi-Fi adapters), you'll get `DLT_IEEE802_11`; if you also have "radio metadata" headers before the 802.11 headers, you'll get something such as `DLT_IEEE802_11_RADIO` or `DLT_IEEE802_11_RADIO_AVS` or `DLT_PRISM_HEADER`.

Do *NOT* assume what the link-layer header type is for the packets you will get from libpcap.  ***ALWAYS*** call `pcap_datalink()` to determine the link-layer header type, and use that to parse the packets; if your code doesn't know how to parse packets for a particular `DLT_` value, it should report an error and exit.

> How do I read further data of packets? If I just read one byte, my program doesn't do anything, every variable gets empty.

Assuming that you record Ethernet data, you need to parse/process data in accordance with  standard specifications. For example, first parse [Ethernet frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame). Even at that point, Ethernet frame can be of variable length. For example, given that tcpdump/wireshark does not record Preamble field, you need to read 15 octets to determine how much more you can/should read.

After you are done with Ethernet frame, you need to parse IP, then possibly UDP and/or TCP. Some other data can be in other formats, but in each and every case you have to carefully study the format specification and parse the data accordingly. Reading one byte will not get you anywhere. So I'd recommend you to start from learning basic network layers - Ethernet, IP, UDP, first, and then get back to the problem of parsing them.

At the end of the day, Wireshark is an open source program that does most of what you want to do as an exercise. Meaning that you can always [download](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) the source code, see what it does  and learn from it.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: See my updates to Vlad's posting, fixing some errors (it is ***NOT*** true that pcap files don't contain the link-layer header type!) and adding some more information.

Comment: @GuyHarris: Yeah, I've missed the type field in there. Thanks for the update!

Comment: A somewhat simpler program that also parses packets is tcpdump; looking at its source might also be useful.